# Validating user input and comparing it to SQL Server database information so that user can login

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm working on a project that tasks users with create an account which are store user account in a database table in SQL Server (I already have this part done).

I'm just having trouble with the log in-side of the form. After the user creates the account, I want them to log in using the email and password and presenter.

I have to parts to the project: forms, which is its own project,and a library which holds my models and SQL connectors. In SQL Server, I have already created the stored procedure.

My question is how do I do the same thing for the login form? In my database, I have different columns such as First name, last name, email, password, and id. What I want to do is have the user enter their email and password and compare it to the information that was added to the database from the user input when they created their account.

I tried creating a new connection to the SQL Server database in the log in form code section, but I found it better if I can have all the database connections and heavy code in the library side of the project.

This is how I created the user and saved it to the database. This code is in my `SqlConnector` class which is apart of my library.

```cs
public UserModel CreateUser(UserModel model)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString("MasterChef")))
    {
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("@FirstName", model.FirstName);
        p.Add("@LastName", model.LastName);
        p.Add("@Email", model.Email);
        p.Add("Password", model.CreatePassword);
        p.Add("@id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

        connection.Execute("spPeople_Insert", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        model.Id = p.Get<int>("id");

        return model;
    }
}
```

This the method from the `Usermodel` class which is used in the `SqlConnector` class and create account form

```cs
public UserModel(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string createPassword)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    Email = email;
    CreatePassword = createPassword;
}
```

This is how I validated user input in the create account form, which then gets sent to the database:

```cs
private void createAccountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateForm())
    {
        UserModel model = new UserModel (nametextBox.Text, 
                                         lastNametextBox.Text,
                                         emailTextBox1.Text,
                                         createPasswordTextBox.Text);
        GlobalConfig.Connection.CreateUser(model);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This form has invalid information, check again!");
    }
}

private bool ValidateForm()
{
    bool output = true;                   

    if (nametextBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        output = false;
    }

    if (lastNametextBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        output = false;
    }

    if (emailTextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        output = false;
    }

    if (createPasswordTextBox.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        output = false;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: This site provides a preview of your question for a reason. Please use it and don't submit if the formatting is a mess. The harder your post is to read, the less likely we are to read it and so the less likely you are to get the help you want. Help us to help you.

Comment: You are effectively asking us how to write a query with a `WHERE` clause that matches two columns. That's all a login is: a query to get a record - maybe just a count of records - where two columns match user input. If a matching record is found then the login is successful. Things are a bit more complex if you are salting and hashing the password but you don't appear to be doing that.

Comment: I already have the query created in sql server. I just don't know how to use implement in C#  thats the biggest thing and everything I looked up talked about creating a new connection which I don't have to do

Comment: Then you should do some general reading on ADO.NET. There are loads of examples and explanation around of executing a query using a `SqlCommand`. You ought to be able to have a go for yourself first.

Comment: Aside... Plaintext passwords in a database? Still? In this day and age? We're doomed. If you must still handle passwords then please at least salt-and-hash them in the database so that they aren't open for direct inspection to every Tom, Dick or Harry with access to the database. Don't encrypt them, don't hash them, salt-and-hash them.

Comment: I would do that if this was for something serious but this more so just a self project and I want to stay simple for now

Comment: That wouldn't pass muster in the real world. Prototypes have a nasty habit of jumping the fence to production on short-to-no notice. Get in the habit of doing things right from the beginning then you don't need to rework things nor allocate time to do so.